# Как подключать html файлы друг в друга при помощи webpack

Tags: webpack, gulp

Недавно перешел на **Webpack 5** с Gulp, раньше в Gulp я мог встраивать html в другой html вот так:

```
<body>
    @@inlude('./header.html')
    @@inlude('./main.html')
    @@inlude('./footer.html')
</body>
```

Это делал плагин [gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include).На webpack есть похожий плагин [file-include-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-include-webpack-plugin), но у меня не получилось его правильно настроить. Как можно сделать то что я хочу в webpack?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.